# Pagination for Custom Loop (loop with foreach)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, pagination

I'm trying to add pagination to a custom loop, but I can't figure out how to do it. When I manage to add "previews" and "next" buttons it always shows the same 10 posts. I found some solutions for a while loop but not for a foreach loop (which I actually never used before). 
This is the loop (is get_posts a problem?) :

```
<?php 
  $news = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 10)); 
  $news['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; ?>

        <?php foreach ($news as $article): ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($article->ID); ?>"><?php echo $article->post_title ?></a></h3>
                <hr>
                <p class="desc"><?php echo $article->post_excerpt ?></p>

        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($article->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($article->ID,'thumbnail'); ?></a>
                <p class="btn_text"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($article->ID); ?>"> Ler mais</a></p>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>


   <?php previous_posts_link( '<<' );
    next_posts_link( '>>', $custom_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { // 'page' is used instead of 'paged' on Static Front Page
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}

$custom_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    //'category_name' => 'custom-cat',
    'order' => 'DESC', // 'ASC'
    'orderby' => 'date' // modified | title | name | ID | rand
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

        <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>
            <div><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        </article>

    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>

    <?php if ($custom_query->max_num_pages > 1) : // custom pagination  ?>
        <?php
        $orig_query = $wp_query; // fix for pagination to work
        $wp_query = $custom_query;
        ?>
        <nav class="prev-next-posts">
            <div class="prev-posts-link">
                <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $custom_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="next-posts-link">
                <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); ?>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <?php
        $wp_query = $orig_query; // fix for pagination to work
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query 
else:
    echo '<p>'.__('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.').'</p>';
endif;
?>
```

Source : http://web-profile.net/wordpress/themes/wordpress-custom-loop/

Comment: Thank you! I'm still  having trouble. When I click on "older entries", I'm redirected to the homepage.